# I can get an HTML/CSS/JS modal to hide, but when shown it does not position correctly or have bg-color or border

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I am assuming that my JS and HTML is correct.  I put my full code in, not so long, so the entire problem can be seen.  I copied several sites CSS strategies,to no avail.  I did try reputable sites, like W3Schools, and javascript.plainenglish.io.

Where am I going wrong?  I don't know what to put in my CSS for #modalContent and I think what I am putting in my CSS for #modalContainer is affecting #modalContent in ways I do not understand. My problem is the the text of my modal content is being shoved all the way to the top left of the modal window, and it does not have a window of its own to hold the modal contents.  Otherwise, when the modal is unhidden, the background covers all of the screen and seems to be working fine.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Modal Popup</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge" />
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="eric_meyer_reset_2.css" /> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <header>
            <h1>JavaScript Modal Popup</h1>
         </header>
         <div id="modalButtonDiv">
            <button id="modalButton">OpenModal</button>
         </div>
         <div id="modalContainer">
            <div id="modalContent">
               <span id="redX">&times;</span>
               <h1>Modal Title</h1>
               <p>Modal content goes here</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   font: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
   display: block;
}

body {
   line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
   quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
   content: '';
   content: none;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
   max-width:1680px;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
}

#wrapper {
   background-color: white;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

header > h1 {
   font-size: 2rem;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 0.67rem 0;
   text-align: center;
}

#modalButtonDiv {
   text-align: center;
}

#modalButton {
   background-color: rgb(28, 132, 56);
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 100px;
   padding: 0.5rem 0;
   line-height: 1.5rem;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 4px;
   margin: 15px 0;
}

#modalContainer {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#modal-content {
   background-color: white;
   width: 450px;
   position: relative;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const openModalButton = document.getElementById("modalButton");
const closeRedX = document.getElementById("redX");
const modalContainer = document.getElementById("modalContainer");

let openModal = function () {
   modalContainer.style.display = "block"
};
openModalButton.addEventListener("click", openModal);

let closeModal = function (event) {
   if (event.target === modalContainer) {
      modalContainer.style.display = "none"
   }
};
window.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

let xCloseModal = function () {
   modalContainer.style.display = "none";
}
closeRedX.addEventListener("click", xCloseModal);
```

To reiterate, there is nothing I can put in #modalContainer and/or #modalContent so that my modal window shows with the text in it, right now only the background of #modalContainer is working, and the closing of the modal window also.

Comment: Have you tried `bottom: 0;` and `right: 0;` instead of `height` and `width` on `#modalContainer`?

Comment: You need to explain "it does not position correctly" as does not tell what you do expect it to do.

Comment: I have tried most everything I can think of, Great, however I will try bottom and right of 0 again, Great.

Comment: Mr. van der Lende, what I mean is that when I give it a bottom and right like Great suggessted it will not follow my instructions.  I will try again and update.

Comment: When I open my modal after adding a bottom 0 and right 0, my modal text stays in the top left of the window, and my red closing x is floated on the right as I have specified. (no change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that I called the div modalContent in my HTML and modal-content in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

William S,
I have edited your code like this,

```js
 const openModalButton = document.getElementById("modalButton");
        const closeRedX = document.getElementById("redX");
        const modalContainer = document.getElementById("modalContainer");

        let openModal = function() {
            modalContainer.style.display = "block";
        };
        openModalButton.addEventListener("click", openModal);

        let closeModal = function(event) {
            if (event.target === modalContainer) {
                modalContainer.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

        let xCloseModal = function() {
            modalContainer.style.display = "none";
        }
        closeRedX.addEventListener("click", xCloseModal);
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        body {
            margin: 20px;
        }
        
        #modalButtonDiv {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #modalButton {
            background-color: rgb(37, 140, 102);
            width: 100px;
            padding: 0.5rem 0;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        #modalContainer {
            display: none;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }
        
        #modalContent {
            background-color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 15%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 80%;
        }
        
        #redX {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 36px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="modalButtonDiv">
        <button id="modalButton">OpenModal</button>
    </div>
    <div id="modalContainer">
        <div id="modalContent">
            <span id="redX">&times;</span>
            <h1>Modal Title</h1>
            <p>Modal content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
       
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks HanKBeatz.  However, a modal popup is supposed to work no matter what is going on with divs, widths, heights, units, whatever.  It is supposed to cover the screen with a background that obscures the rest of the screen and brings the attention to the modal window created somewhere within the background. I was trying to simulate being in the middle of an HTML file and building a modal window.  You got it close and I am playing around with it now, but the answer does not meet the requirements for answering the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#modalContainer {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            z-index: 1;
            background: red;
        }
        
        #modalContent {
            background-color: rgba(000, 00, 0, 0.5);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
           
        }
        
        #redX {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 36px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

You can get the background color like this also!!